# How can I implement Ajax Form Validation in Sonata Admin Bundle?

Tags: php, ajax, validation, symfony-2.1, sonata-admin

I am newbie in Symfony. I use Sonata Admin Bundle Symfony 2.1. How can I implement Ajax Form Validation? Are there any solutions?

Comment: asavchenko: You can refer this link http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1

Comment: I was searching for solutions, but did not find them. I tried to write own validator based on Entity, but it failed.

Comment: I use in my entity custom field constraints. Sonata admin bundle validate form use this rules, but validation is not by ajax.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that works in Sonata Admin 2.1 but you can try the following if you have for example a *sonata_type_collection*. 
Set the option: **'cascade_validation' => true** that should do the job.

That works quite fine at current Sonata Admin (2.3).

```
$formMapper
         ->with('customer_contacts', array('collapsed' => true))
            ->add('customer_has_contacts', 'sonata_type_collection', array('cascade_validation' => true), 
                array(
                    'edit'              => 'inline',
                    'inline'            => 'table',
                    'sortable'          => 'position',
                    'admin_code'        => 'acme_demo_bundle.customer_has_contacts',
                )
            )
        ->end();
```